# what is detatch & non-detatch threads in iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsthread

Whats the difference between detach and non-detach thread in iPhone? 
The iPhone "Threading Programming Guide" documentation says that

- By default the NSThread class creates detach threads
- And it also says that a Detached thread means that the thread's resources are automatically reclaimed by system when the thread exits. In the same way , how does it happen in non-detach threads?

Thank You.
Suse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This relates to the underlying pthread implementation. Read up on pthread_detach and pthread_join to understand the differences.

In practice, you probably don't care and Cocoa/NSThread do the right thing for you automatically.

And to clarify, there's no way to create a non-detached thread using NSThread. You'd have to use the low-level thread API for that.